# How to start two memcached instances on two different ports from docker-compose?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, memcached

I want to start two docker-compose services of memcached. I am using the docker standard memcached image for both instances. Memcached should be able to use environment variables to change the port it is listening on, but it does not seem to work.

My docker-compose.yml

```
...
memcached-server:
    image: memcached
    environment:
      MEMCACHED_PORT: 11211
    ports:
      - 11311:11211
    networks:
      - my_net

memcached-server-lock:
    image: memcached
    environment:
      MEMCACHED_PORT: 11212
      MEMCACHED_CACHE_SIZE: 128
    ports:
      - 11312:11212
    networks:
      - my_net
...
```

The containers are starting correctly but the env variables do not seem to be picked up:

```
0ae76227b72b        memcached                            "docker-entrypoint..."   17 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:11311->11211/tcp mobidesk_memcached-server_1
ab3682361dad        memcached                            "docker-entrypoint..."   17 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       11211/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11312->11212/tcp  mobidesk_memcached-server-lock_1
```

Does anybody know which variables to use. Or is it something else I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the docker port used by memcache, you can simply have it like this:

```
memcached-server:
    image: memcached
    ports:
      - 11311:11211
    networks:
      - my_net

memcached-server-lock:
    image: memcached
    environment:
      MEMCACHED_CACHE_SIZE: 128
    ports:
      - 11312:11211
    networks:
      - my_net
```

Anyway the variables you're using are ok. You shouldn't use ports different from the ones EXPOSEd by the Dockerfile.

Comment: I know they could run on the same port because they live in different containers. But in this case I want them to be on different ports. The exposed port should change with the given variable. When I look into the Dockerfile of memcached I see that the port is not configurable. I think I will have to create my own Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to edit the .sh file. Is enough to use the "command" option directly in docker compose:

```
  cache:
    image: memcached:latest
    command:
      - '-m 128'
```